# How Get Parameter From HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api

I post the 4 parameters on the payment Gateway URL , in response server send back the parameters named auth_token & postBackURL.

I don't under stand that how to get these parameters (auth_token & postBackURL) from respose in ASP.NET MVC ????

Below is my code.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("storeId", "1234"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("amount", "1000"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("postBackURL","http://www.smmotors.org"));
        values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("orderRefNum", "1101"));

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        HttpResponseMessage response =   client.PostAsync("https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf", content).Result;
```

---

**Below is the Plug-in Integration Documentation .**

The merchant needs to POST following parameter to the Easypay on the following URL:

Sandbox Environment:
https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf

 amount
 storeId
 postBackURL
 orderRefNum

After successful redirection the customer would land on the Easypay Checkout Screen where there is a form to be filled regarding the transaction information.

2. After completing the form in Step 1 the customer will be pressing the Proceed Button and lands back on the merchant website on the same URL given in postbackURL variable in the first step. This will be a confirmation screen on merchant’s website to perform a handshake between Easypay and merchant’s website. The Easypay sends back a parameter named auth_token to the postbackURL which is sent as a GET parameter. Now the merchant needs to post back following two parameters again to the following URL:

Sandbox Environment:
https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf

 auth_token
 postBackURL

After this redirection the Easypay authenticates the auth_token sent by merchant with the one it has in the previous step, and upon successful authentication it will make customer land on the successful checkout screen sending back following two variables to the second postBackURL:

 status
 desc
 orderRefNumber

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this to get response key

```
  public ActionResult AdvPaymentResponse()
    {
        List<PaypalAddDataValueModel> keyvalueList = new List<PaypalAddDataValueModel>();
        var postdata = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
        foreach (var item in postdata)
        {
            PaypalAddDataValueModel datavalue = new PaypalAddDataValueModel();
            datavalue.Key = item.ToString();
            datavalue.Value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[item.ToString()];
            keyvalueList.Add(datavalue);
            // var data = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[item.ToString()];
        }
        AdvPaypalResponse obj = new AdvPaypalResponse();
        obj.AVSZIP = keyvalueList[0].Value;
        obj.BILLTOEMAIL = keyvalueList[1].Value;
        obj.TYPE = keyvalueList[2].Value;
        obj.ZIPTOSHIP = keyvalueList[3].Value;
        obj.BILLTOLASTNAME = keyvalueList[4].Value;
        obj.BILLTONAME = keyvalueList[5].Value;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry i can't under stand , can you please give example with my code.